# Statistical queries on a list of customers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been given a list of simple Customer objects to work with. This would be an example of a customer list:

```
customers = [
    Customer(active=True, age=38, gender='F'),
    Customer(active=False, age=18, gender='M'),
    None,
    Customer(active=False, gender='F'),
    None,
    Customer(age=64),
    Customer(active=True, age=23),
    None,
    Customer(age=23, gender='M'),
    None,
]
```

The list contains `None` values for customers that have been deleted and `active`, `gender` and `age` are not required properties of `Customer` and so they can be un-set.

To find the number of active customers:

```
def number_of_active_customers(customers):
    # Assumption: A customer is only active if active=True is set
    return len([customer for customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active is True])
```

To find the number of inactive customers:

```
def number_of_inactive_customers(customers):
    # Assumption: Deleted customers also count as inactive
    return len([customer for customer in customers if customer is None or customer.active in (False, None)])
```

To find out if the list of customers has any `None` values:

```
def list_has_none_values(customers):
    # any() won't work here since a list of None's always evaluates to False. We don't need to know the length
    # of the list so we can simply loop over each element and return True when we encounter the first None value
    for customer in customers:
        if customer is None:
            return True
    return False
```

To find out if the list has any customers with `active=None`:

```
def list_has_active_equals_none_customers(customers):
    # any() works here because we can stop processing at the first True value in the list
    return any([customer for customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active is None])
```

To find the average age of male customers:

```
def average_age_of_male_customers(customers):
    try:
        # Round average to 1 digit
        return round(
            mean(
                (customer.age for customer in customers if customer is not None
                 and customer.gender == 'M' and isinstance(customer.age, int))
            ),
            1)
    except StatisticsError:
        # Return 0 when there are no male customers
        return 0
```

My code should be as pythonic and efficient as possible. I'm fairly sure I got it, I'm just second-guessing myself a little. This is not a school assignment and I am allowed to ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do more data analysis on this afterwards, then this might be a good time to learn about [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which has data frames, allowing you to modify whole records at a time.

First, read in your list into a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[customer.active, customer.age, customer.gender]
                   for customer in filter(None, customers)],
                  columns=["active", "age", "gender"])
```

Here the `filter(None, it)` filters out all `None` values (and all falsey values, but an object that exists is by default truthy, so unless you overwrote `Customer.__eq__` or `Customer.__bool__`, it should be fine).

Now we have a data frame like this:

```
print(df)
#   active   age gender
# 0   True  38.0      F
# 1  False  18.0      M
# 2  False   NaN      F
# 3   None  64.0   None
# 4   True  23.0   None
# 5   None  23.0      M
```

To make handling of the left over `None` values easier, we replace them with `numpy.nan`:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace([None], np.nan)
print(df)
#   active   age gender
# 0   True  38.0      F
# 1  False   NaN      M
# 2  False   NaN      F
# 3    NaN  64.0    NaN
# 4   True  23.0    NaN
# 5    NaN  23.0      M
```

Now to get to your tasks:

- Number of active customers:

  ```
  active_users = df.active.sum()
  # 2
  ```
- Number of inactive customers:

  ```
  deleted_users = sum(customer is None for customer in customers)
  inactive_users = len(df) + deleted_users - active_users
  # 8
  ```
- Any customer deleted:

  ```
  deleted_users > 0
  # True
  ```
- Any customer with active=None:

  ```
  df.active.isna().any()
  # True
  ```
- Average of male customers (NaNs are automatically ignored):

  ```
  df[df.gender == "M"].age.mean()
  # 20.5
  ```

  - If there are no people of that gender, it will return a `numpy.nan` instead of `0`, though:

    ```
    df[df.gender == "X"].age.mean()
    # nan
    ```

From there on you can also do more fancy stuff:

- Average age per gender:

  ```
  df.groupby("gender").age.mean()
  # gender
  # F    38.0
  # M    20.5
  # Name: age, dtype: float64
  ```

Using this makes your code both more efficient to write (since most things you could want to do are already implemented) as well as faster to run (since the methods are usually implemented in C, instead of running in Python. So if you have lots of customers, this will certainly be better.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate review! I had thought about using pandas but the assignment was to keep it as simple as possible. Definitely a good option for the future though.

Answer (score 2):

I want to encourage you to be more pythonic in a couple of ways.

#### 0. Provide reviewable code!

You didn't provide a solid block of code that I could copy/paste. You didn't provide even a dummy class definition for `Customer`. You got three "likes" before my review, and an answer from at least one other person (@Graipher). Respect the time of the reviewers and readers by making their jobs as stress-free as possible: provide reviewable code that compiles, runs, includes all the necessary imports, etc.

#### 1. Write PEP-8 code

Seriously: go and read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It's not that long, it's not difficult, and it's full of advice that, while you may not agree with it, will provide you with a consistent, readable Python coding style that will seem familiar and "Pythonic" to other coders.

In your specific case, I mean for you to tighten up your names and start structuring your code using docblocks:

```
def number_of_active_customers(customers):
    # Assumption: A customer is only active if active=True is set
    return len([customer for customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active is True])
```

Should be something like:

```
def count_active(customers):
    """ Return number of active customers.

        A customer is active if the .active attribute is set to True.
    """
    return len([customer for customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active is True])
```

#### 2. Use iteration instead of lists

Let's look at that last function again:

```
def number_of_active_customers(customers):

    return len([customer for customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active is True])
```

What you are doing is calling `len` on a *list comprehension* in order to count the number of customers that are active. The problem is that you're *building a list* in order to count it. Lists consume memory and slow things down, while iterating will produce the same result without allocating any storage that you will immediately throw away at the end of the expression.

Tragically, you can't just replace your list with a [*generator expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/4029014) and get the same result, since generators don't come with a `len` method. But you can check out the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and find `quantify`:

```
def quantify(iterable, pred=bool):
    """Count how many times the predicate is true"""
    return sum(map(pred, iterable))

def number_of_active_customers(customers):
    return quantify(customer for customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active is True)

# or ...
def number_of_active_customers(customers):
    return quantify(customers, lambda c: c is not None and c.active)
```

#### 3. Laziness is next to ... godliness?

Well, maybe laziness is next to lethargy. But it's also one of the [*three virtues of a **great** programmer*](http://threevirtues.com/) and that has to count for something!

You say:

```
customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active is True

customer in customers if customer is None or customer.active in (False, None)
```

Be lazy! In Python, the truthiness of `None` is false. And the expression `a is b` is a boolean expression. And the expression `a in b` is a boolean expression. So go ahead and say:

```
customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active

customer in customers if customer is None or not customer.active
```

#### 4. Don't Repeat Yourself!

How can I be saying this? Let's look at your code:

```
return len([customer for customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active is True])

return any([customer for customer in customers if customer is not None and customer.active is None])

(customer.age for customer in customers if customer is not None
 and customer.gender == 'M' and isinstance(customer.age, int))
```

There sure is a lot of repetition in there!

Consider `customer in customers if customer is not None`. What is that? Well, sadly `None` is a valid customer entry since that how deleted items appear. But couldn't we just pick a name for that? How about **remaining customers?**

```
def remaining_customers(customers):
    """Return only non-deleted customers (deleted items are set to None)"""
    return (customer for customer in customers if customer is not None)
```

As soon as you define that one function (note: it returns an *iterable* not a list) everything else gets shorter! To wit:

```
return len([customer for customer in remaining_customers() if  customer.active])

return any([customer for customer in remaining_customers() if customer.active is None])

(customer.age for customer in remaining_customers() 
 if customer.gender == 'M' and isinstance(customer.age, int))
```

**But wait! There's more!**

Because in addition to some *conditional expressions* that are repeated, I see a lot of *structure* that is repeated. Many of your functions take the form "iterate over the customers, selecting values that match some condition". I wonder if there's a shortcut for that?

You could use the built-in [`filter(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#filter) function,
but that doesn't quite get it:

```
return quantify(filter((lambda c: c.active), remaining_customers(customers)))
```

However, a little applied laziness leads to the observation that most of your operations boil down to:

- ask if any customer matches a conditon
- count how many customers match a condition
- select all customers matching a condition and return them

You can write those functions directly:

```
from typing import Callable, Iterable

def any_customers(customers, where: Callable[[Customer], bool]) -> bool:
    """Return whether the callable returns True for any customer."""
    return any(where(c) for c in customers)

def count_customers(customers, where: Callable[[Customer], bool]) -> int:
    """Count when callable returns True over all customers."""
    return quantify(customers, where)

def select_customers(customers, where: Callable[[Customer], bool]) -> Iterable[Customer]:
    """Yield each customer where callable returned True."""
    return filter(where, customers)
```

With those in hand:

```
def count_active_customers(customers):
    return count_customers(remaining_customers(customers), lambda c: bool(c.active))

def count_inactive_customers(customers):
    return count_customers(customers, lambda c: c is None or not c.active)

def have_deleted_customers(customers):
    return any_customers(customers, lambda c: c is None)

def have_active_none_customers(customers):
    return any_customers(remaining_customers(customers), lambda c: c.active is None)
```

Finding the average age of male customers requires two steps because of the necessity to extract the `.age` field. If you write your `select_customers()`
function with enough parameters, you might be able to eliminate that (take a `fields=` parameter, return tuples, except with only one field return the values directly, maybe parse simple SQL statements, etc...). But you probably ain't gonna need that!

```
def avg_age_males(customers):
    male_customers = select_customers(remaining_customers(customers),
                                      lambda c: c.gender == 'M')
    try:
        # Round average to 1 digit
        return round(
            mean(c.age for c in male_customers if isinstance(c.age, int)),
            1)
    except StatisticsError:
        # Return 0 when there are no male customers
        return 0
```

Comment: thanks for your elaborate review! Some great tips here.